# Two non-obviously identical random variables that can be shown to be identical via their characteristic functions

Tags: probability, distributions, density-function, characteristic-function

It is well known that a characteristic function (CF) is uniquely associated with a probability density function (PDF). Knowing this, I was nonetheless intrigued by a remark in a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mYhca1p26n4) I have been watching. The remark implied that CFs can prove useful when it is not easy to show directly that two random variables have the same PDF but one can more easily show that their CFs are identical.

I was unable to think of any example illustrating the point. Can anyone suggest an example where it is not obvious (admittedly always somewhat subjective!) that the PDFs of two random variables are identical but that can be shown to be so via the CFs?

Comment: Showing the distribution of the limit of a sequence of random variables has the same density as a normal distribution is the essence of the Central Limit Theorem and is usually done with characteristic functions

Comment: If you know the characteristic functions of Gamma distributions, then it is very easy to use characteristic functions to show that the sum of two independent Gamma distributed random variables with the same rate or scale parameter is another one.